# docs.ros.org down/broken?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

docs.ros.org seems to be broken.  For example here is the link for the AsyncSpinner for melodic (I get a 404): http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1AsyncSpinner.html

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343400/docs.ros.org-down/broken?/) by [tyler-picknik](https://answers.ros.org/users/48265/tyler-picknik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2020-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like there was a regression in rosdoc_lite I've just merged the fix here: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdoc_lite/pull/95

With a rerun of the documentation job for roscpp the file is restored. Any other package that regressed due to this will recover any missing documentation the next time that there's a change.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1